# Value of the integer counter must be shared among all the users of your web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

•   This page must contain a button by which value of a shared integer counter can be increased.
•   Value of the integer counter must be shared among all the users of your web application i.e. if any user increase the counter, the counter value will be increased for all users.

Comment: Stack overflow is for questions. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use Signlar to achieve your requirement.

When the client click the button, you could call the signlar' server method to use `Clients.All.SendAsync( )` to send the increase count number to all client.

More details about how to use Signlar, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0).